# How do I fit an img in a given frame

Tags: html, css

I am using two break points in my CSS.

- One for Iphones where no image should be seen Only the resume content can be seen. -- Working Fine.
- Second, for desktops where the image is aligned to the left side of the resume content. This is where I am facing a problem The image in the left is not  100% here. Only a part of it shown. The image and the content should be placed next to each other.

Also, please let me know if there is any other way other than splitting the `<section>s`.
Since the image is on my local system, I have added the screen shot of my webpage below:

[image: ResumeWebpage]

Below is my code:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
h1.hidden{
  display: none;
}
.container{
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}
.tag {
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: rgb(43, 93, 240);

}

.main{
  text-align: left;

}

}

@media screen and (min-width: 601px)
{
html {
    box-sizing: border-box
}
*,
*::after,
*::before {
    box-sizing: inherit
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
p {
  margin: 0 0 1em;
}
.container {
  width: 1920px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.picture, .resume {
  position: fixed;
  width: 960px;
  padding: 3.125rem;
  text-align: left;
}
.picture {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.intro {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 55% auto 0;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 1.35;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.background {
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url("../img/profile.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:left;
  filter: brightness(90%);
}
.intro em {
  color: #3ee6bf;
  font-style: normal;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.resume {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Hind, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.9375rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.818;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.part {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 3em;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.part:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.sidebar, .main {
  float: left;
}
.sidebar {
  width: 10%;
}
.main {
  width: 90%;
  padding-right: 25%;
}
.tag {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: rgb(43, 93, 240);
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>The Mobile Experience</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:500,700|Hind:400,600,300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <!-- current design is from http://rafaelderolez.be/, would need to be replaced if lab approved -->
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <section class="picture">
      <div class="intro">
        <h1 class="hidden">Hello, I'm Jenna!</h1>
        <h1 class="hidden">I make <em>websites</em>.</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="background">
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="resume">
      <section class="part">
        <div class="sidebar">
          <span class="tag">Jenna Garcia</span>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
          <p>
            Hello! I'm  Jenna. A web developer from New York City, currently working at a Silicon Valley startup called, Fomotograph.
          </p>
          <p>
            I create websites using HTML5, CSS3, Sass, and JavaScript. I also create full web applications using Ruby on Rails and Django.
          </p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="part">
        <div class="sidebar">
          <span class="tag">Projects</span>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
          <h4>Collector of Cats</h4>
          <p>
            A web application that shows you a random photo of a cat, and allows you to add the photo to your album of cat photos.
          </p>
          <h4>Artify Me</h4>
          <p>
            Turn a regular photo of you into a work of art. Want to look like the Mona Lisa? Artify Me!
          </p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="part">
        <div class="sidebar">
          <span class="tag">Work</span>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
          <div>
            <h4>Fomotograph</h4>
            <div class="date-range">September 2015 - Present</div>
            <p>Silicon Valley, California<br />
            Web Developer</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h4>Automotify</h4>
            <div class="date-range">December 2012 - September 2015</div>
            <p>London, England<br />
            Web Developer</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h4>Jenna's Web Development Consultancy</h4>
            <div class="date-range">August 2011 - December 2012</div>
            <p>New York, New York<br />
            Web Developer</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that you have a conflict of intentions expressed so it's hard to know how to help.

On one hand you want the image to take up the full height of the screen. This is displayed with your use of `height: 100vh;`. On the other hand you don't want the image to be covered up and you want to see the image as a whole. To see the image as a whole and keep its full height with 100vh, you'd have to squish it up horizontally, no?

My suggestion would be to decide whether when the screen gets smaller the image should be covered, or if you're prepared to lose some height on it in order to preserve its natural aspect ratio. The last thing you want is for it to be squashed.

If you are prepared to lose some height, I suggest splitting the image and the text and give them widths that are percentages.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you change position in your html the classes background and container, so in the css determine the percent of position of each class to left or right from body and retire the propriety height from .background class. I am a beginner, but I hope help you if not please tell me.

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <section class="picture">
      <div class="intro">
        <h1 class="hidden">Hello, I'm Jenna!</h1>
        <h1 class="hidden">I make <em>websites</em>.</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="background">
      </div>...
</body>
```

by

```
<body>
  <div class="background">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <section class="picture">
      <div class="intro">
        <h1 class="hidden">Hello, I'm Jenna!</h1>
        <h1 class="hidden">I make <em>websites</em>.</h1>
      </div>...
  </div> 
</body>
```